# How to convert Mono<List<T>> to another Mono<List<T>>?

Tags: java, mono, nonblocking

I am writing a non-blocking program and I know that I shouldn't use `block()`. 
In the following code, I want to solve without using `block()`.

i have two repositorys.

```
Mono<Version> version = versionRepository.getVersion();
Mono<List<StandardField>> fieldList = fieldRepository.getFields(version.block().getVersionId());
```

and convert method is..

```
private Mono<List<ConvertField>> getConvertFields() {
    return versionRepository.getVersion().map(version -> {
               return fieldRepository.getFields(version.getVersion()).map(fields -> {
                   return fields.stream()
                           .map(field -> ConvertField.builder()
                                   .field(field.getField())
                                   .dataType(field.getDataType())
                                   .name(field.getName())
                                   .build()).collect(Collectors.toList());
               });
            });
    }
```

However, this phenomenon occurs.

Required type:
`Mono<List<StandardField>>`
Provided:
`Mono<Object>`
no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Mono conforms to `List<StandardField>` inference variable R has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: `List<StandardField>` lower bounds: `Mono<R528674>`

I want to return `Mono<List<ConvertField>>` by combining `Mono<Version>` and `Mono<List<StandardField>>`. Can you help me?

Comment: First snippet has `getVersionId()`, second has `getVersion()`. If both of them is actual code, then one of them must be wrong. If second one is wrong, that causes compiler type inference to fail, which to you would look like what you described. So, are both actual code?

Comment: sorry typo.. `getVersion()` It is correct. However it is not a problem with typos.

Comment: it would be better if u provide your sample classes for us to try out.